# Gradle dockerCompose plugin keeps lastly configuration for all tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy, configuration

In my spring boot project I need keep two `dockerCompose` plugin configurations for tests and for local application.

for example:

```
dockerCompose {
    useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/postgresql-test.yml']
    isRequiredBy(project.tasks.localPostgreSqlTest)
    removeContainers = true
    stopContainers = true
}
```

and

```
dockerCompose {
    useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/postgresql-test.yml']
    isRequiredBy(project.tasks.localPostgreSqlTest)
    removeContainers = true
    stopContainers = true
}
```

Following this structure I've configured task `localPostgreSqlTest`:

```
task localPostgreSqlTest {
    dockerCompose {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/postgresql-test.yml']
        isRequiredBy(project.tasks.localPostgreSqlTest)
        removeContainers = true
        stopContainers = true
    }
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
}
```

and other one `localPostgreSql`

```
task localPostgreSql {
    dockerCompose {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/postgresql-local.yml']
        isRequiredBy(project.tasks.localPostgreSql)
        removeContainers = false
        stopContainers = false
    }
    tasks.bootRun.dependsOn(it)
}
```

Considering this configurations in separate way everything works as expected.

Adding all configuration to `build.gradle` at the same time behavior changes: lastly met `dockerCompose` configuration is used in both my tasks.

I sure that the issue is with my gradle configuration and groovy knowledge.

### So question is

How to modify my tasks declarations `localPostgreSqlTest` and `localPostgreSql` to have for each of them their own plugin configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using
[avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin](https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin)
Plugin:

`dockerCompose` is a global configuration and is supposed to be used at
top level.  So once you are setting the same thing in different blocks,
it still only writes to the same location, therefor the last value wins.

To make your setup work, you would have to use [nested
configurations](https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin#nested-configurations):

E.g. at top level:

```
dockerCompose {
    dev {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/postgresql-local.yml']
        isRequiredBy(project.tasks.localPostgreSql)
        removeContainers = false
        stopContainers = false
    }
    test {
        useComposeFiles = ['docker-compose/postgresql-test.yml']
        isRequiredBy(project.tasks.localPostgreSqlTest)
        removeContainers = true
        stopContainers = true
    }
}
```

Comment: foolowing this approach I cant start tests after `composeUp` and before `composeDown` (in case I'm using `dependsOn(tasks.test)` inside of `doFirst` or `doLast` everyshing fails). I tried similar  trick before your post, I thought I've missed something and just repeat other attempt.

Comment: regular `composeUp` is no longer configured and therefor should fail very fast - there are now tasks prefixed with `dev` e.g. `devComposeUp` etc.  But without sharing your actualy problem, there is not much to suggest here.

Comment: I wrote about sequence of call. The point is that compose ctarts after tests, but I need compose first. The sequence call with your proposal is: 1. `test`, 2 `composeUp`, 3 `doFirst` block, 4 `doLast` block. I've detected it using additional task, because experementing with tests I fail on 1st step, because `test` needs started docker.

Comment: 5. `composeDown`. Let me know please if you need different details from my side.

Comment: Feel free to add another question, where you show the problem.  Imho this answers your original question and how you have some different problem.

Comment: I do not think this answer completely covers my question and described issue. Proposal exposes different issue can't be correct one. Other case we can ask help from stackoverflow comunity. Also please pay attention, that shared configurations in question work in correct way if they are separated (I mean they have correct sequence calls)